# Write down the negations of following statement of $∀x(x^2≥x)$

Tags: logic

Write down the negations of following statement
$∀x(x^2≥x)$

[image]

Comment: What statement?  Please do not use a link-they can rot and people don't like to click through.  Then please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation of the statement above is:

$\exists x(x^2<x)~ \vee ~ \forall x(x^2\neq 2)$

Note that $\neg\forall \to \exists$ and vice versa $\neg\exists\to\forall$. Also $\neg\wedge\to\vee$

Comment: Thank you dear.